# Which scope is generally used for spring beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

For a Spring-based Java web application, how can I structure the controller, service, DAO class efficiently using Spring beans?

Currently my structure is like this

`TestController.class` (Prototype scope) → `TestAPI.class` (Prototype scope) → `TestService.class` (Singleton scope i.e default)

I've used Singleton scope in `TestService.class` because it contains only utils.

Is this is right practice or should I go with thread, session based scope?
What's the industry wide practice for this?

Answer (score 4):

In general, unless it's absolutely necessary, you should always opt for Singleton-scope. It's generally rare in fact to use any other type of scope and it's only done in very specialized circumstances.

The question you should always ask when deciding on a scope is "What state will this object need to maintain?". In general, the answer should be "none". You should always strive for stateless beans whenever possible. However if there is state you want to be able to inject into objects, then the question is, what is the scope of this state? So for instance, is this state scoped to the request, is it scoped to a specific call of a method, is it scoped to a user session?

With that said, always the default should be to make your components stateless, and deviate from that only when it's necessary or advantageous.